# ¿Por qué es posible acceder a constantes dentro de una clase sin instanciarla?

Tags: c#

Buenas, tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public class Material
{
    public class Compuesto
    {
        public const int Peso = 33; // El peso del compuesto siempre es el mismo.
    }
    public int GetPesoCompuesto()
    {
        return Compuesto.Peso;
    }
}
```

Y el código `Main()`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Material Mat = new Material();
    Console.WriteLine("Peso del compuesto: " + Mat.GetPesoCompuesto()); // Funciona, retorna: 33
    Console.WriteLine("Peso del compuesto: " + Mat.Compuesto.Peso); // Error.
    Console.WriteLine("Peso general: " + Material.Compuesto.Peso); // Tambien funciona.
}
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Por qué puedo acceder a la constante `Peso` sin instanciar la clase en ninguna variable, es decir, no debería la constante solo definirse cuando creo una instancia de su clase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cual seria el sentido de tener que instanciar la clase si el valor sera siempre el mismo.

Las variables y propiedades solo se acceden cuando instancias la clase porque el valor que asignes puede ser diferente de una instancia a otra.

En cambio con una constante esto no sucede, por mas que crees varias instancias el valor sera el mismo, por eso es que se puede acceder directo con el nombre de la clase

[Constantes (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/ms173119.aspx)

veras que las constantes solo pueden tener tipos simples como ser int, string, short, etc, pero no puedes crear una const de otra clase o de object, esto es porque estos tipos de datos puedes cambiarlos al ser tipos por referencia.

En el link comenta:

> El acceso a las constantes se realiza como si éstas fuesen campos estáticos, porque el valor de la constante es el mismo en todas las instancias del tipo.

Comment: En ese caso, ¿Por qué el segundo intento de acceso falla? Si estoy accediendo desde una instancia a la constante?

Comment: no es que falla, ni siquiera puedes llegar porque te falta la forma de crear una instancia de la clase Compuesto. Es mas aunque crees la instancia la const no aplica por instancia por lo que no podras accederlo